# How to attach a doorbell transformer to a plastic junction box?

Tags: junction-box, transformer, doorbell

My son's doorbell isn't working, I'm not getting any voltage, and I traced the wiring to the transformer located in the basement behind a finished ceiling used for a light fixture. I would like to relocate the new transformer in a nearby unfinished part of the basement. (How did they attach the transformer to the back or side of that blue plastic outlet box?)

I found a couple of 1-gang outlets but they are in blue plastic boxes.
[image: like this one]

My new transformer is the type with a screw on connector for attaching to one of the holes in a junction box but I don't see any way of doing that to this type of box. Is there a trick to this? Or do I need to install a different box next to it and run power there?

Answer (score 2):

As I Understand It:

- To do it wrong, you simply drill a hole in the box, which is
  presumably what was done.
- To do it right you need a box with a knockout for a hole, which will
  normally be a steel box.

Comment: No, a hole was not drilled in the original box.

Comment: Then perhaps it's not attached at all...

Comment: If you want a plastic box with KOs, those do exist -- look for boxes made for use with ENT (aka smurf tube).